# How do I define an intent filetr to launch Google Now's voice search?

Tags: google-search

I am having trouble getting my Android app launched in response to a voice search. I've looked at what others have posted here and based on that i have added these line to my manifest.

```
    <activity android:name="<my fully qualified class name>"
              android:exported="true"
              android:label="@string/app_label">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>

    </activity>
```

My application's label is two words - think Hello World - concatenated to form a single string.

I have a file named `searchable.xml` in my app's /res/xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
</searchable>
```

When I say

OK, Google search for blah, blah blah on Hello World

Google correctly recognizes my speech but doesn't launch my application. If I use the ADB command which specifies my package name then my activity is launched with the proper search intent. (I published my app in the Play Store only to be able to test search)

Are there constraint's on what label might be that I don't know about or am I forgetting something.

Comment: what is your app package name so we can help debug it?